# How I can respond to this major revision?

Tags: peer-review

Recently I have received major revision on manuscript submitted to springer journal. In the manuscript I have devise a methodology by which very decent results are derived and I called these results by name "X" in manuscript. The reviewers comments are as follow:

> **First reviewer**: This reviewer praised my work but told me that my results should not be named as "X" because from properties of results I should better name the results as "Y" and he further suggested to correct some typos. Overall this reviewer is willing to accept my work.
>
> **Second reviewer**: This reviewer asked me  that if  my results are of type "X", then I should prove certain properties that are required to call results as "X".  He further states that, if my results are not of type "X",  then the title, abstract, introduction of manuscript need to be reviewed.

Now actually my result are really not of type "X", they are of type "Y" as suspected by second reviewer and I mistakenly called them as "X". This name "X" is used in title, abstract and introduction. I guess changing name from "X" to "Y" would not effect the quality of my work.

But, if I do change the name of results from "X" to "Y" would the second reviewer likely to suspect the quality of my work or is it possible that he would reject my work ??

PS. Except naming, there is no other problem in my work.

Comment: How much time do you have for the revision? If it's not defined, you can focus more on the problem and prove some properties for the results to be "Y". In peer review, anything is possible in terms of accepting/rejecting papers. Even Nobel physicists have some paper rejected before the ideas were accepted in the community. Just give your best action for this paper and hope for the best.

Comment: @MikeyMike I have three months for revision.

Comment: @IgotiT Lots of time!

Comment: @jakebeal: The time is not problem here, the only thing that I need to do is to change the name from "X" to "Y" (I am admitting my mistake here) and this would not effect the remaining content of my work, the thing that I am worried about is how reviewer would perceive my correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the question is here. It seems like everyone agrees that the proper name is Y, so the only thing you can do is change it to Y and resubmit.

My guess is this will clear up the confusion of the second reviewer.  And if you don't change the name he will surely reject your paper, because after all it isn't about X.  But it's really irrelevant: you know what the right thing is to do, and you have to do it, even if the consequences turn out to be negative.

Yes, it's possible your paper will be rejected. That is always a possibility whenever you submit a paper for publication.  Get used to living with it.

Comment: Fortunately my paper got accepted after honest revision suggested by you.